# Git Tower hotkey (low priority)

Tags: hotkeys, git-tower

Myself and coworker both have the same version of Git Tower, when he is focused on an uncommitted change and hits the spacebar, the file is staged for a commit. When I hit the spacebar nothing happens. What's up with that? I like my hot keys! The spacebar checks boxes in my browsers but not in Git Tower. Like I said in the title, this is a "I'm being lazy and don't want to use the mouse, low priority" question.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, we don't do lazy questions here.

Comment: Isn't being lazy a programmers forte? Writing code so that you only have to write it once and not over and over? DRY?

Comment: Same problem here. It was working, now its not. Really painful. The alternative shortcut key is Cmd+Alt+A, but its awkward. Not sure how this happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enable `Full Keyboard Access` in your Keyboard preference pane, see the image below. Checkboxes (like in Git Tower) are normally not editable/selectable through keyboard focus, so that is why the spacebar also doesn't work.

[image: Full Keyboard Access]